# CSS: Prevent single character from going to new line

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I have a problem with preventing a single character from going to a new line

I have the following problem with single character going into new line:

[image]

The problem is with character `:`

I have set on wrapping div following styles

```
flex-basis: 150px;
flex-shrink: 0;
white-space: normal !important;
word-break: break-word;
```

But the `:` symbol always goes into a new line, how would I make it that it pull previous word with him if I goes to a new line, or to stay on the same line

Answer (score 0):

You can use the whitespace css property for that:

```css
white-space: nowrap;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: Because the text gets cut off then :/

Comment: Then we need to see some of the code. The HTML and a bit of CSS. Could you add those to your question?